# macOS Ventura 13.2 Differences between ~/Library/Containers/Mail/Data AND ~/Library/Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app, disk-space, library

I've migrated my Mac probably from Tiger (maybe clean installed once in between), so the Mail folder structure is probably a bit messy. Nevertheless, I just got a new mac and migrated with Migration Assistant again and found my new Mac has much less space left than the previous one. Long story short, I ended up deleted quite a lot of mail attachment from ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail Downloads.
According to my search, it should be safe to remove them (right?). 20GB space recovered.
I've tried rebuild the mailbox with Download Attachment "None" selected and that 20GB was still untouched...Anyhow, a lot of time wasted.

My question now is it seems there are similar sized V10 folders in ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail AND
~/Library/Mail

I see some posts online said the /Container is a sandbox and it's a link to other places, but is it normal to take similar amount of space? In my case,
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail took 51.5 GB (I deleted the 20GB Mail Downloads from here)
~/Library/Mail took 81.8 GB

The structures are not exactly the same but some folder names in V10 (they both have V10) are exactly the same.

Is it normal for Mac Mail to use double the disk space? Or it's the migration left over?
If it is normal, any other mail client can perform as-good search feature and take much less space?

If it's not normal, what might be the best course of action to keep the Mail disk usage under control? If I can confirm it's not normal, I'll be happy to remove all accounts (and remove all the mails/attachment, don't know how atm though) then redownload them from the IMAP/Exchange servers. I "think" they are still all kept on the servers.

BTW, the Apple chat and phone support is useless in my experiences...

Thanks!

Comment: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail` is usually an alias to `~/Library/Mail`. If you're using IMAP server, then delete everything locally and re-sync from the server. I would generally advise against manually deleting stuff in the Finder from the Mail's database.

Comment: Thanks @benwiggy when you said delete everything locally, do you mean by removing the account from Mail? Then add back to resync. 

Also if it’s alias, it shouldn’t take that much data right? Thanks

Comment: I've tried to remove on one of my gmail account. Weirdly enough. the Mail/OS only removed the files in ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail and made that gmail account to be an OrphanedAccount - xxxxx. 

On the other hand, the files in ~/Library/Mail are still there with the original folder name taking still quite a lot of space. 

I'm re-syncing that gmail account now. A new folder pop up in ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail and nothing in ~/Library/Mail yet. Hopefully I did not make things worse.

Comment: Just checked another 2 Macs at home and their ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail folder seem to be an alias as it should be. Not like my largest one seem to be working on its own without pointing to ~/Library/Mail 
Not sure what happened here. Anyone knows if there is a way to get this sorted? 1) Reinstall macOS (overwriting some things)? 2) Full clean install? Thanks.

Comment: Spoke to an Apple Support who finally knows what he is talking about. He confirmed it's likely the migration (not sure when though, could be earlier than Ventura) may mess up with my Mail folders. He provided a much better solution. Closed Mail. Changed my problematic folders in both locations to Mail1 and Mail2. Reopened Mail. It seems to link ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail back to ~/Library/Mail with new created /Mail folders in them. Now laptop is downloading msgs from the servers. Hopefully all work well and hopefully this helped someone. Do this with cautious thou.

Comment: Another detail is the ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail folder seem to change the name from Mail1 back to Mail by itself and there are many /Mail folders in this location. So mark it with color before doing anything will help. Anyhow, if you need to do something like this, prob. better have an Apple guy on the phone with you.